My computer won't move on to an unfamiliar screen
To run scDALI, I deleted python3.10 installed on iMAC and installed python3.9.15 and pip.
But the next day, when I turned on the computer, a screen I had never seen before appeared, and screens that I had no idea what they meant continued to appear.
I tried rebooting or searching on the internet, but I couldn't find a solution.
Why is this happening??

My computer only has Ubuntu.

You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; eg. if you change the default python3 version on a Ubuntu Desktop you can expect problems (as many tools use python3 and they won't work at all, or won't work reliably if version is changed).  Did you change the default version? (many versions can be installed but default cannot be changed) and what Ubuntu product are you using (Server? Core? Desktop?) and what release?

Given the default Ubuntu version was 3.10, it is most likely 22.04

Changing python version is going to cause major problems because many components of Ubuntu depend on it.
First, install the package ubuntu-desktop to restore the necessary packages for GUI.
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^

In case you cannot connect to the internet without GUI, then you will have to reinstall Ubuntu. In the extreme case, you can connect to internet by USB tethering with your phone.
Reboot, and the GUI should be restored.

Afterward (either after installing GUI or reinstalling Ubuntu), to safely install python3.9 use the deadsnakes ppa.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.9

To run Python 3.9, run the command python3.9. Alternatively, set up a python virtual environment (google how to).
Do not change the default python version.
